# certifications for C# Developers

Tags: c#

I am working as a software developer. Are there any certifications for C# Developers?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/01/do-certifications-matter.html (FYI, the one who wrote it is the same who created this site)

Comment: "@Andreas Brinck" sure, but still some employers want that "papers"+ Microsoft Certification is a milestone to the Gold Partnership for the firm you work for(every certified worker gives some points to the firm).

Comment: Yes, recruitment agents and HR people loves certifications, so they're very useful for getting interviews with many companies.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck, just because some one written about certification in his blog (doesn't matter he/she is creator of what and it's his personal opinion) doesn't mean certification have no value. Just get the certification and add it to your resume and see where you stand from crowed.

Comment: Are you even motivated to do any search at all? If not choose another career path.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See this: [Microsoft Visual Studio Certification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/visual-studio-certification.aspx). Just choose the version of VS(.NET Framework) and go prepare for the exam.

Also good video preparation materials are at:

- [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight-training.net/) (you can get 3 free month with [Visual Studio Dev
  Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/) program as of 13.09.2017)
- [CBTNuggets](https://www.cbtnuggets.com/)
- [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=.net) (they often have discounts, so just wait for ~10$ per course)

Good Luck!

Comment: The link has been removed. Please update if possible.

Comment: @vivek , fixed, thank you.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-483.aspx